# Grails dbCreate=update always create existing join table

Tags: hibernate, grails, join

```
public class Scenario_Head {

        String scenarioName
        String scenarioDesc

        static hasMany = [ rules: Rule ]
}

public class Rules_Head{

        String rulesName

}
```

During `grails run-app`, hibernate keep on creating the Join Table for the two even though the Join Table is already existing in my database. My `dbCreate` in `DataSource.groovy` is `update`.

I'm not sure if this behavior only persist if it's a Join Table.

Could anyone help me on this? somewhat brief explanation of this behavior?

Thanks in advance for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Data source `dbCreate` **update**, creates missing tables and indexes, and updates the current schema without dropping any tables or data ([link](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource)).

Looking at your domain, there are some issue with your dmain.

- Use camelcase for domain name, avoid '*', Camelcase domain name corresponds to table name separated by '*'. Ex: `MyDomain` corresponds to table `my_domain` table.
- If table name is different than the domain name use mapping to declare table name explicitly. 
  Ex: `table schema: Holders.grailsApplication.config.agi.oms.database.schema.name, name: '<TABLE NAME>'`

Also, you haven't shown `Rule` domain.

Comment: Thanks Armaiti.
correction on Scenario_Head code:
      static hasMany = [ rules: Rule_Head ]

in my Scenario_Head domain, I have this code:

static mapping = {
       joinTable name: 'ScenarioMaster_GfcRuleMaster', schema: 'dbo'
       // which ScenarioMaster_RuleMaster will be the join table name
       // table name for Scenario_Head is ScenarioMaster and for Rules_Head is RuleMaster
}

should I also add this code in my Rules_Head domain??